# Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session after update to hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

After updating to hibernate 4 and changing some needed settings I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/ESBCollector] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:328)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.getSession(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks like hibernate3 is still being used to open the session. Any ideas on which i forgot to do?

Comment: That should be clear from looking at the stack trace... You still are using the old `OpenSessinInViewFilter` instead of the hibernate4 one.

Comment: Looks like your spring version is not compatible with hibernate 4 You should also upgrade your hibernate version.

Comment: Yes but I didn't know where to find this. But your comment did get met to thinking and I found it know so that's solved. Thanks. (@M. Deinum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to change the openSessionInViewFilter in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `mvn dependency:tree` and search for Hibernate 3 jars in your output. When you find the dependencies adding Hibernate 3 to your dependency tree, you need to simply exclude them, like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No he doesn't. He simply used the wrong `OpenSessionInViewFilter` the hibernate3 version instead of the hibernate4 version.

Comment: True, but the issue I described here is still possible, so I'll leave the answer as such, for it might help someone else.

Comment: Although it might it isn't a valid answer for this question and as such not really helpful. The question clearly states that hibernate4 is used and there are some left overs from hibernate3.

Comment: Hibernate classic session classnot found exception.                     
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
   </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.15.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

You are using hibernate4 however your `web.xml` still used the [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`] for hibernate3 instead of the [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`] for hibernate4.

To fix find the filter in the `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>osiv-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

And replace the 3 with a 4.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>osiv-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you have imported old (hibernate3) classes within code, like

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
// needs to be replaced to 
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
```